# why don't extend 0b10101010 to 4bytes(Int) automatically when doing right shift operation

Tags: java

here's a piece of code:

```
byte c = (byte) (0b10101010);
byte d = (byte) (c >> 1);
System.out.println(d);
```

The result is -85. (I know the reason because the byte c extends to int automatically before doing right shift operation(higher 3 bytes all make up 1))

here's another piece of code:

```
byte c = (byte) (0b10101010 >> 1);
System.out.println(c );
```

The result is 85. so my question is before doing right shift operation, why the binary code (0b10101010 don't extends to int (ff, ff, ff, 0b10101010) as if the upper piece code?)

Comment: The result of the first one is not `-85`, it's `-43`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literals like 0b10101010 have type `int` so there is no need to convert it to a bigger type. Also, it's a positive number so sign extension would not be applied to begin with.

Comment: so the key point is 0b.... have type int, I think the 0xff also is a int and is a positive number, right? @Joni

Comment: All integer literals have type int, except if you use the suffix L to make a long. 0xff is 255 in decimal which is positive, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "extend to int". What's happening is sign extend, meaning that the topmost bits will be filled with the sign bit (1 in case of negative numbers, 0 in case of non-negative numbers).